# jQuery make divs the same height on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a problem which you can look at here http://jsfiddle.net/dng2P/4/

If you click the detail button it shows you information and then if you click the "Points Statement" button it slides a layer down.

My problem is that I'm trying to make the main `booking details` div the same height as the `points` div if it's bigger and then when you click close put the main `booking details` height back to what it was originally.

It's half working as the main `booking details` div becomes the same height as the `points` div but just doesn't go back to what it was originally

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Jamie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's this?
http://jsfiddle.net/dng2P/8/

All you did wrong was failing to keep the original height around properly. You only declared `bookingdetailheight` as a local variable which means it got re-declared for every toggle, and removed after every toggle was complete. I tied the original height to the DOM element with using `.data()`, it simplifies things when you might have people opening two of those toggles simultaneously.

I got on a roll though, so tidied up a bit and made the outer animate along with the inner. Oh and please look up the proper traversal methods in jQuery, `parent().parent().parent().find()` is asking for trouble. I think there's some left in parts I didn't look at.

Comment: Thank that works brilliantly appreciate the help and patience

Comment: jamie, glad you got a working solution... i 'knew' the bookingdetailHeight variable was causing the issue. nice to see alexander taking it 'home'... +1 nice one

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look at the jsfiddle code. I think the value that you take into the bookingdetailHeight should be declared outside the scope of the .points toggle function. that may help a little. just gonna try that :)

[edit] - didn't solve it -sorry :(

Comment: I've change the first link to another one which i'm currently working with and it has two properties

Comment: ok, will take a look at that and report anything back that i find.

Comment: jamie, i didn't fully get to the bottom of it - however, i've got a feeling that the parent() hierarchy could be an issue potentially. i think there's a way to use parents() to navigate around deep tree structures. might be best to attack that avenue 1st. sorry to have added nothing to the party here :(